# After $npm install, Getting Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I just came back to work on a React project after working in the Rails environment and found that I cannot run any NPM commands in my Mac terminal. I've tried all the remedies that I have come across but none have worked. The bigger issue is what caused this and how can I avoid it again.

Here is the error. What do I need to do? Please help.

```
$npm install            

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
```

I have tried the following:

```
$brew update
$brew uninstall node
$brew install node
```

After which the following commands come up as so when $which npm was unknown command before:

```
$which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm

$which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

I even tried running:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm -v
```

but get the same error as above while

```
/usr/local/bin/node -v
v9.11.1
```

works fine.

added the following to my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/node:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH
```

I have also tried:

```
$brew uninstall --force node
$brew link --overwrite node 
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1
To relink: brew unlink node && brew link node

$rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

then,

```
$node install
```

but that does not work, either.

```
$echo $NODE_PATH
```

does come up empty, so I may need to added the following to my .bashrc.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

That does not work either.

Comment: do you have `require('../lib/utils/unsupported.js')` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I  don't have any reference to unsupported.js. NPM commands don't work on any project or directory.

Comment: Looks like I was able to fix the issue by downloading and installing Node from https://nodejs.org. Did $brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node, then downloaded and installed from nodejs.org. I have no idea why the brew installation of Node and NPM stopped working. If anyone has any idea, please let me know.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19997

Comment: None of below-written answers fixed my problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Uninstall node `brew uninstall --force node`
2. Remove the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder
3. Install it again `brew install node`

Comment: same for me BUT I had to get rid of the modules files present under "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/" before doing the reinstall.

Comment: worked for me as well but only after deleting `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: Same here, only worked after removing the`/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder. @Lucas Lopes, maybe update your answer to add that?

Comment: i had to remove `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` only and not the whole folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: First should install the brew command  : sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper    After  run the 1. uninstall node command then remove the folder using this command : sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules.  finally run the 3 and press Enter

Answer (score 10):

Assume this happens on MacOS, below solution works for me.

1. brew uninstall --force node
2. Visit https://nodejs.org/en/ and download the LTS version and install, the error was gone

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me after installing yarn.

in a terminal:

```
brew uninstall --force --ignore-dependencies node
brew install node
```

if you have trouble symlinking node, in the same terminal:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib
brew link --overwrite node
```

Check that your re-installation worked by typing the following in the terminal:

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue after upgrade my mac. I tried different solutions available on stack overflow and nothing work for me.

> This solution works for me.

1. Uninstall node all version `brew uninstall --force node`
2. Install it again by this `brew install node`

First point remove all node versions if available.

Done. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

"If you're a Homebrew user and you installed node via Homebrew, there is a major philosophical issue with the way Homebrew and NPM work together."

Kudos to Dan Herbert for the solution.

Comment: His suggestion of --without-npm did not work for me. That is an invalid option

Answer (score 3):

**Remove all file from following folder**

A)C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

B)C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

and `install node` again

then execute command "`npm install -g @angular/cli`"

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answered solved my issue. After reinstalling Node, I still got the same error (even when I just wrote `npm -v`).

I followed [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1766219) (removing **everything** called node and npm), which solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution to the problem was reinstalling the node using the official installer from https://nodejs.org (Mac OS).

**Solution:**

1. Download node installer from https://nodejs.org
2. Install it

**P.S.** The problem appeared after yarn installation.

Answer (score 1):

One other suggestion after trying these that finally worked for me was simply upgrading my node by downloading the latest via the download and package installer from here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Before doing this trying to run any npm command gave me the same error brought in OP's question

npm commands started working for me after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but in my case I get the same error, because, my index.js is inside de src folder, make sure that you are in the seme directory of your index.js to run

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened after I performed a machine-wide clean-up of all node_modules folders. I had node installed with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and I started getting this error, no matter what node-related action I wanted to trigger:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
```

I solved it by doing the following:

1. Restarted my computer
2. [Uninstalled nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298)
3. Installed a different node version

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error after `brew upgrade`on mac.
I did `brew postinstall node` and that fixed it.